# Prove that $A=B$ considering: $(A \cap C = B \cap C) \land (A \cup C = B \cup C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So this is the thing I've got to prove:
$ (A \cap C = B \cap C ) \land ( A \cup C = B \cup C ) \Leftrightarrow A = B $

I can understand this intuitively but the formal proof is taking me some time. So far, I've got this:

$ (A \cap C \subset B \cap C ) \land (B \cap C \subset A \cap C ) \land ( A \cup C \subset B \cup C ) \land ( B \cup C \subset A \cup C ) \Leftrightarrow (A \subset B) \land (B \subset A) $

$ (\forall x) (x \in A \land x \in C \Leftrightarrow x \in B \land x \in C ) \land (\forall x) (x \in A \lor x \in C \Leftrightarrow x \in B \lor x \in C ) \Leftrightarrow (\forall x)(x \in A \Leftrightarrow x \in B) $

But I feel like going nowhere. I assume this has something to do with the transitive property, but I'm not sure how to apply it here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I answered something like that not too long ago. **EDIT:** Note quite the same, but it's the third part of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730904/can-you-conclude-that-a-b-if-a-b-and-c-are-sets-such-that).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh it's a duplicate I didn't notice. u.u

Comment: No worries. It happens all the time. Many times it's much easier to post the answer again than to find a duplicate link...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x\in A$ then there's two cases

- if $x\in C$ then $x\in A\cap C=B\cap C$ then $x\in B$
- and if $x\not\in C$ then $x\in A\cup C=B\cup C$ then $x\in B$

hence we proved that $x\in B$ and then $A\subset B$. The other inclusion is similar. Conclude.

Comment: Why won't using the union relationship in the $x \in C $ part do the trick as well?

Comment: If $x\in C$ then we can't deduce that $x\in B$ using the union relationship since $x\in B\cup C$ is possible even $x\not \in B$.

Comment: Very nice, Sami!

Answer (score 0):

To do this on the logic level, one approach is to use the fact that $\;\lor\;$ distributes over $\;\equiv\;$.

For the right hand part, this results in
\begin{align}
& A \cup C \;=\; B \cup C \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"set extensionality; definition of $\;\cup\;$, twice"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \lor x \in C \;\equiv\; x \in B \lor x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: $\;\lor\;$ distributes over $\;\equiv\;$"} \\
(*) \;\;\; \phantom{\equiv} & \langle \forall x :: (x \in A \;\equiv\; x \in B) \lor x \in C \rangle \\
\end{align}

Now for the left hand side we can do something similar:

\begin{align}
& A \cap C \;=\; B \cap C \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"set extensionality; definition of $\;\cup\;$, twice"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \land x \in C \;\equiv\; x \in B \land x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: negate both sides of $\;\equiv\;$ -- to prepare for the next step"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \not\in A \lor x \not\in C \;\equiv\; x \not\in B \lor x \not\in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: $\;\lor\;$ distributes over $\;\equiv\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: (x \not\in A \;\equiv\; x \not\in B) \lor x \not\in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: simplify by negating both sides of $\;\equiv\;$"} \\
(**) \;\;\; \phantom{\equiv} & \langle \forall x :: (x \in A \;\equiv\; x \in B) \lor x \not\in C \rangle \\
\end{align}

Finally, combine $(*)$ and $(**)$ and use laws of predicate logic to conclude that together they are equivalent to $\;A=B\;$.