# Proof about sets: $(A \cap C = B \cap C \land A \cup C = B \cup C) \implies A=B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have undefined sets $A, B, C$.

How can I prove that this statement is true?

> $$ (A \cap C = B \cap C \land A \cup C = B \cup C) \implies A= B $$

I absolutely do not know how to start or what to use. Please try to advise me or how to proceed. Thanks

Comment: You say you absolutely don't know how to start or what to use, I say [I don't believe you](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). I think that if you just think back to all the other times you've been asked to prove that two sets are equal (surely this isn't your first such problem), you can get a few ideas for things you can try. Maybe it works, maybe it doesn't.

Comment: @Arthur, i don't know how to proceed in evidence or how to verify their correctness. I try to understand but I do not know where I'm making a mistake

Comment: http://karagila.org/2015/how-to-solve-your-problems/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unions and intersections: $(A \cup B = A ∪ C) \land (A \cap B = A ∩ C) \implies B = C.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468080/unions-and-intersections-a-cup-b-a-%e2%88%aa-c-land-a-cap-b-a-%e2%88%a9-c-implies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a contradiction. Suppose there is $x \in A$ which is not in $B$ ($x \not\in B$). As $A \neq B$ and $A\cup C = B \cup C$, $x\in C$. Therefore, $x \in A \cap C$. As we know $A\cap C = B \cap C$, $x \in B \cap C$. Hence, $x\in B$! which this contradicts by the first assumption. and we can proof that all $x$ in $A$ are in $B$. In the same way we can say that all $x$ in $B$ are in $A$. Therefore, $A = B$.

Comment: $$
\forall x \in A \subseteq B \wedge \forall x \in B \subseteq A
$$
Is correct when i write it like this?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \in A$.

Case 1: $x \in C$. Then $x \in B \cap C$, thus $x \in B$.

Case 2: $x \notin C$. Then $x \in B \cup C$, thus $x \in B$.

Therefore we have shown that $A \subseteq B.$

The reversed implication can be shown by similar arguments.

Answer (score 0):

$$A = A \cup (A \cap C) = A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C) = (A \cup B) \cap (B \cup C) = (B \cup A) \cap (B \cup C) = B \cup (A \cap C) = B \cup (B \cap C) = B$$