# Prove that $A \cap B = A \cap C$ and $A \cup B = A \cup C$ if and only if $B = C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to learn some elementary set theory and found the following problem in my textbook. There was no solution given, so I post mine here. There is one step which I am unsure of. Can someone tell me if this correct or give some advice to improve it?

**Proposition:** $A \cap B = A \cap C \iff B = C$

**Proof:** The proposition contains 2 implications

$$A \cap B = A \cap C \implies B = C \label{1}\tag{1}$$
$$B = C \implies A \cap B = A \cap C \label{2}\tag{2}$$

We proof $\eqref{1}$ by it's contrapositive $B \neq C \implies A \cap B \neq A \cap C$. We show that under the assumption $B \neq C$ we have $A \cap B \neq A \cap C$ by establishing, that the 2 implications

$$A \cap B \implies A \cap C \label{1.1}\tag{1.1}$$
$$A \cap C \implies A \cap B \label{1.2}\tag{1.2}$$

cannot both be true. In the case of $\eqref{1.1}$ $x \in A \cap B$ leads to $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. For $x \in A \cap C$ to be true, we need $x \in A$ and especially $x \in C$. The first is obviously true.

Now comes the step were I have problems, since I'm unsure, that I have properly expressed my ideas.

For the later, since $B \neq C$ we can assume that there is a $x$ with $x \in B$ but $x \notin C$. This would lead to $\eqref{1.1}$ being false. Otherwise we have a $x$ with $x \in C$ but $x \notin B$. In this case for similar reasons, $\eqref{1.2}$ would be false. Either way, one of $\eqref{1.1}$ or $\eqref{1.2}$ has to be false. Thus $B \neq C \implies A \cap B \neq A \cap C$ is true which proofs $\eqref{1}$.

For the proof of $\eqref{2}$ we suppose that $B = C$ and show, that

$$A \cap B \implies A \cap C \label{2.1}\tag{2.1}$$
$$A \cap C \implies A \cap B \label{2.2}\tag{2.2}$$

are true. For $\eqref{2.1}$ it follows from $x \in A \cap B$ that $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. For $\eqref{2.1}$ to be true we need $x \in A$ and $x \in C$. Again, $x \in A$ is plainly true. Now, since $B = C$, we know that $x \in B \iff x \in C$. This leads to the parts $x \in B$ and $x \in C$ form the previous statement to be equivalent, which completes the proof of $\eqref{2.1}$. Similarly we can show that $\eqref{2.2}$ is true. Thus $\eqref{2}$ is proofed.

Therefore we have $A \cap B = A \cap C$. $\blacksquare$

I post this since, for me, this is quite a complicated construction, so I might have gotten something confused. Perhaps there is a shorter proof, but my measures are still limited. Any advice is welcome. Thanks!

**Edit:** To answer to first comments the complete problems was as follows.

Prove by contradiction or otherwise that $A \cap B = A \cap C$ and $A \cup B = A \cup C$ if and only if $B = C$.

I took these to be two separate statements which I could solve individualy. I guess I was wrong with that.

Perhaps someone can give a quick sketch of a proof so that I can complete it on my own?

Comment: This proposition is wrong, for example $A\cap B=\emptyset=A\cap C$ then $B=C$ does not follow at all.

Comment: $\Rightarrow$ is false. $A=\{1\}, B=\{2\}, C=\{3\}$

Comment: There is likely additional context in the textbook that has not been provided. Perhaps $B\cup C\subseteq A$. In this case, as the comments give counterexamples when this is not true, this condition would have to be used somewhere in the proof.

Comment: Is this supposed to be, perhaps, that $A\cap B=A\cap C$ **for all sets $A$** is equivalent to $B=C$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I've tried to read the suggested proof as if that was true and it might be that but the proof doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: There is this related question: [$A∩B=A∩C$ and $A∪B=A∪C$. Show $B=C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2042489/746312)

Comment: And there is [Prove that if $A∩B=A∩C$ and $A∪B=A∪C$ then $B=C$ by contrapositive](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3840998/746312)

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct.
Counterexample:

$A=\{1\}, B=\{1,2\}, C=\{1,3\}$.

Then $A\cap B=A\cap C=\{1\}$ but $B\neq C$.

So the implication "$\Rightarrow$" does not hold.
The other implication "$\Leftarrow$" is obviously true.

Besides some typographical 'nonsense' you should not try a proof by contraposition, but a direct one.
So lets see where $\Rightarrow$ goes wrong.

Let $A\cap B=A\cap C$. We want to proof $B=C$.

For that we have to proof $B\subseteq C$ and $C\subseteq B$.
Let $x\in B$. We have to show that $x\in C$.

If $x\in A\cap B$, then $x\in A\cap C$. Hence $x\in C$.
If $x\notin A\cap B$ then $x\notin A$.

But we can not conclude that then $x\in C$, as $x$ does not have to be.
So we need a stronger assumption for this implication to hold.
The problem is, that we do not know anything about how the sets $A,B,C$ are related, so it is impossible to proof this implication.

Answer (score 1):

> To *prove*: $[A \cap B = A \cap C] \iff B = C$

Other responses to the posting have clearly demonstrated that the assertion, *as is,* is false.

Personally, I found the comment of Arturo Magidin intriguing as a remedy for the assertion:

> Is this supposed to be, perhaps, that $ A \cap B = A \cap C$ **for all sets** A is equivalent to $B=C$?

My alternative approach is to provide an intuitive (i.e. visual) explanation of **why** the assertion is false.

In the image below, the set $A$ is represented by the large   square. 
Both $A \cap B$ and $A \cap C$ are located in the upper right hand corner of set $A$. 
As represented in the diagram, the premise stipulates that these two intersections are identical.

In effect, if your focus is confined to what is *happening inside set* $A$, then **yes**, the two sets $B$ and $C$ are identical.  However, the premise provides no information on what is happening outside of set $A$.

So, you can not use the premise of what is happening inside of set $A$ to draw any conclusions about what is happening outside of set $A$.

[image]

Comment: Yes, andI think similarly $A \cup B = A \cup C$ it focusing on the identity of $B$ and $C$ for "something happening outside of A", as you described intuitively. Please note my edit. I will try to put this and the other thoughts in comments and answer into a new solution. Thx @user2661923

Answer (score 1):

So given the comments and answers (thx especially @Cornman for the idea), I changed the title of the post to the correct problem. I will try to give a better solution here. Please excuse if my first post was somewhat confused. I have just started to learn math and gotten lost.

**Problem:** Prove that $A \cap B = A \cap C$ and $A \cup B = A \cup C$ if and only if $B = C$

**Solution:** If we assume $B = C$, $A \cap B = A \cap C$ and $A \cup B = A \cup C$ are quite obviously true, so I will omit a detailed proof here.

For the converse, we have to show that we have $x \in B \iff x \in C$. Let be $x \in B$. We show that this implies $x \in C$. We can discern two cases. Either we also have $x \in A$ or $x \notin A$. If we have $x \in A$, then also $x \in A \cap B$. Then by assumption $x \in A \cap C$ and so $x \in C$. The second is $x \in B$ but $x \notin  A$. Then we can't use our assumption $A \cap B = A \cap C$ but we also have $A \cup B = A \cup C$. Now surely $x \in A \cup B$ and this implies $x \in A \cup C$. So, since $x \notin A$, we have $x \in C$ as required.

The proof for $x \in C \implies x \in B$ follows the same arguments with $B$ and $C$ interchanged. So we have established that $x \in B \iff x \in C$ and thus proofed that $A \cap B = A \cap C$ and $A \cup B = A \cup C$ if and only if $B = C$. $\blacksquare$

As always, corrections, improvements and comments are very welcome.

Answer (score -3):

$B=C$

=> $A-B = A-C$

=> $A-A\cap B = A- A \cap C$

=> $A \cap B = A \cap C$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).